# how to get Cookie curl from?

Tags: php, http, curl, cookies

I am trying to get content of the page: I use google dev tool (network) and use "copy as curl" which gives me:

```
curl 'http://www.example.com/default.aspx/GetAnnonces' -H 'Cookie: `ASP.NET_SessionId=eolrcogrk1owhmpbsogwd0mf; EPC_alerte=;`
```

This works fine for a while, I guess beacuse of the session life period.

My question is:

Where the SessionId "eolrcogrk1owhmpbsogwd0mf" comes from and how to generate it so I can access the page any time ?

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the `Set-Cookie` HTTP response header of the page you visited. If you're trying to use cURL in PHP it will automatically handle cookies for you and you can set `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` with [`curl_setopt`](http://php.net/curl-setopt) to retain cookies even after the request is complete.

If you just want to see the response headers you could also use `curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true)` and look at the `Set-Cookie` response headers. Though there's no practical reason for doing this for most typical use cases since cURL will just handle the cookies for you like your browser would.